# Problem with implementing the word error checking code

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a code that will load words from the dictionary into the hash table structure and then compare the words with the sample text and print out how many errors there are. Unfortunately, I still have a problem with creating the load function where it loads words from the dictionary into the hash table. I work in Visual Studio Code and when I run the code I get: zsh: abort
"/Users/....../Projects/Code/hash_table/"hash_table"

I noticed that the problem occurs when I start writing a while loop...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cstdio>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large" 
const unsigned int N = 26;

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char word[N + 1];
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *table[N];


int hash_function(char *word)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        value = value + tolower(word[i]);
    }
    int key = value % N;

    return key;
}

void load()
{
    FILE *file = fopen(DICTIONARY, "r");
    
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        cout << "There is a problem with opening dictionary" << endl;
    }

    char word[N + 1];
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        struct node *ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(ptr->word, word);
        int key = hash_function(word);

        ptr->next = table[key];
        table[key] = ptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //load dictionary to a memory

    const char *dictionary = DICTIONARY;

    load();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake - in dictionaries I had words with a maximum of 45 characters and in my program I incorrectly assumed the longest word length to be 26 (N = 26).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).